# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row (laravel5)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, mariadb

at first, I'm sorry for poor english.

I have created tables in MariaDB(innoDB, laravel5) as shown below :

*user table

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

*article table

```
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

*tags table

```
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

*article_tag table

```
   Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->
        on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->
        on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

so when I try to insert values into article_tag table i get:

```
insert into `article_tag` (`article_id`, `tag_id`) values (3, 9);
```

*error message

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mmdance`.`article_tag`, CONSTRAINT `article_tag_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `article_tag` (`article_id`, `tag_id`) values (1, 9))
```

I've seen the other posts on this topic, but didn't solution.
thanks for your help. thanks.

Comment: And what don't you understand about the error?  You are inserting ids but the references values don't exist in the reference tables.

Comment: oh.., sorry, I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply import the Schema facade where you are creating/updating a record.

```
\Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
// Your query
\Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Comment: Whats the point of having foreign key constraint if you want to disable it whenever creating or updating a record. That's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the foreign key and you are good to go . 
or make some reference key to connect to the base table